# Unable to connect internet on a docker container running on GKE pod

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine

We have a GKE pod running with Jenkins image having docker installed in it. When I tried to build a image using Dockerfile on this Jenkins GKE pod, It is not working as background containers created while building image from Dockerfile are unable to access internet to fetch data.
[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: By the way you describe it, it looks like there is a networking configuration issues that does not allow egress traffic to the internet. How do you know you are not able to access the internet, have you got any timeout / any other error? 
The better you describe the issue, with errors, with screenshots, with examples of tests, etc, the better the chances you got someone can help you with this.

Comment: Hi. I have added a error screenshot. First few lines show my Docker file which i am using to build a test image using docker build command on a Jenkins pod running in GKE cluster. Issue is that the intermediate docker container being created does is not able to access ubuntu repo center through internet to fetch update whereas internet is working fine on GKE Jenkin pod as per last few lines of screenshot.

Comment: Are you running a GKE private cluster?  Looks like you may have to configure Cloud NAT in order for pods to access the Internet.

Comment: Yes, I am using GKE private cluster using Cloud NAT for pods to access internet.

Comment: @user260834 can you share the GKE private cluster configuration, including the NAT config you have there please. If NAT was configured correctly, you would be able to fetch resources outside the node. Please share the output of `kubectl cluster-info` and `kubectl get nodes -o wide` plus any other info you think is relevant

Comment: Ah - so you are running Docker in Docker to build images?

Comment: Yes i am running docker inside a jenkins pod on GKE cluster Now trying to build docker images here in which intermediate container has to fetch data from internet which is failing. Till pod level internet is working fine.